# ProTools not recognizing an M4V file

Tags: pt

Editor sends me m4v files and ProTools does not recognize it as a movie when I attempt to import.

I push through compressor-mp4 setting and it spits out a usable movie. The frame rate is now 29.97 but the editor says the frame rate was 24, that is the frame rate of the OMF. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mp4s are the bane of my existence lately.  Its the web standard, so video guys think that audio post want that, but of course PT is completely incompatible, as it QT pro.

ask your editor for a mov file.

Sometimes changing the extension in the finder to mov works, but generally just get your editors out of the habit of delivering mp4 for audio post work.

Answer (score 2):

Open it and export a new file from Quicktime Pro to a file type you know will work with Pro Tools.

I know exactly what you are going through right now - it happens to me a lot when I set up to mix ADR.

I'm pretty fortunate because I have an Avid team downstairs who I can just send it to and they'll convert it to pretty much whatever I need.

Sorry to hear you're having trouble today. Wish I could be of more help -

Answer (score 0):

By doing either of these things, will it mysteriously change the frame rate?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use MPEG Streamclip to convert movies to play nice with PT:

http://www.squared5.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've pretty much narrowed it down.  The MV4 file is in 23.98 and so is the OMF.  PT LE does not have 23.98 support so the editor is bouncing a new mp4 and OMF so I can edit myself to death in the next two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ProTools LE will not support anything but .mov files. The MV4 container is not going to work. If it's spitting out the wrong frame rate from Compressor, could it be due to the settings? At any rate, you should try to get an intraframe compressed .mov file.

Answer (score -1):

Or are OMF's mysteriously in 24 fps sometimes?

Comment: In the version of Media Composer the video editing team works with that I receive videos to mix from usually has a tough time with 24 fps footage and it syncing up in the OMFs they give me. It's a known issue and I think the most recent version of Media Composer fixes it.